# Кнопка "назад" в левом верхнем углу

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toolbar

Здравствуйте. Помогите с проблемой: как добавить кнопку "назад" в левый верхний угол экрана. Везде написано, как это сделать через `Actionbar`, но не сказано, можно ли это сделать `Toolbar`.

Код выглядит так:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

И xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все осталось по старому - `в onCreate`

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ;)

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.myIcon);
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           ...
       }
 });
```